# Reference Request: ADE Resolution and McKay Correspondence

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I was wondering if there's sort of a canonical introduction to the McKay Correspondence in relation to this ADE singularity story?  I've seen some incomprehensible physics sources, but I was hoping for something very geometric, perhaps also with physics component from a purely mathematical perspective.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Best introduction I know are these lecture notes http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/McKaybook.pdf by Igor Dolgachev.

Classical (2D) McKay correspondence was upgraded to an equivalence of derived categories in Tom Bridgeland, Alastair King and Miles Reid, "Mukai implies McKay".

Also Miles Reid have a webpage with links to papers about various generalizations of this correspondence: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/McKay/

Finally, I want to mention that a version of McKay correspondence were proven by Maurice Auslander in the paper "Rational Singularities and Almost Split Sequences". There he described maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules over simple surface singularities in terms of the representation theory of the finite group of the same ADE type.